# Узнать, сколько значений в массиве. Sql

Tags: sql, массивы, postgresql

Работаю в программе PgAdmin.
Имеется массив с данными, нужно узнать, сколько значений находится в массиве

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, phonenumber, COUNT(languages)
FROM person
GROUP BY 1
```

Через COUNT(languages) выводит только цифру 1, хотя значений в массиве больше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT firstname, 
       lastname, 
       phonenumber, 
       array_length(languages, <измерение массива>), -- длина по конкретному измерению
       cardinality(languages) -- длина по всем измерениям
FROM person
```

подробнее: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/arrays